# Memory leakage when moving from DiffArray to Data.Vector

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, quickcheck

After changing the data structure from [diffarray](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diffarray) to [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.9.1) the memory blows up (grows infinitely) during one of the QuickCheck tests.

The code is hosted at [GitHub](https://github.com/EdgarGomes/DeUni). The dev branch contains the ill code and the master one runs well. Apart from minor changes the only commit which could have any effect on that is this [one](https://github.com/EdgarGomes/DeUni/commit/651ca40043213989394af0910a2c1f8ef90480a0). In order to run the QuickCheck routines one should run the executable *tester*. It seems that small length vectors don't crash the program, but when it gets longer the program slows down and finally blows the memory up.
Another thing that intrigues me is the fact that I'm having a similar problem in an other of my libraries while rendering XML files. For small files (<400k) it runs slow but with no crash and for larger files the memory blows up. The Data.Vector is also involved in that library. I have the intuition these problems are related.

**Edit:** I've finally isolated the part of my code that reproduce the memory leak and put it into a single file which can be found [here](http://hpaste.org/65687). Now I'm using IArray that behaves as well as DiffArray. To alternate between IArray and Vector one have to modify the lines 49, 93 and 101.

Comment: Diffarray tries to store updates as small deltas w.r.t the array.  Vector will copy the entire array.  My guess is that this exposes that you are not strict enough (too lazy) somewhere and thunks hold too many old copies of the data and this is killing the allocator.

Comment: Can you provide a very very short example from the test suite?

Comment: If you solve your own problem, post it as an answer and accept it, instead of editing it in the question.

Comment: @Chris Kuklewicz - Thank you! I've found the bug when I was assembling a shorter version of my code. Although, I can't explain what was wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved** Actually the problem was on the generation of vectors by QuickCheck. The original Arbitrary instance for Vector was the following:

```
instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Vector a) where
  arbitrary   = liftM2 Vec.generate arbitrary arbitrary
```

which compiles but gives a memory leak. The problem can be solved if the vectors are generated from lists. Like this:

```
instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Vector a) where
  arbitrary = Vec.fromList <$> arbitrary
```

I still don't know way what was the reason of such a bug....

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus - Very well thought out.

Comment: it is OK for you to [accept your own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it) (after some waiting period perhaps).